# CXF Custom Security Token provider with Token Store

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, cxf, bipro

I try to implement a Security Token Service (Server side) with a requested UsernameToken and my service should response a token, which is generated by cxf.
I use JAVA, Spring Boot and a java-based configuration.

I have some problems to implement a custom Token Provider and using the default tokenstore from cxf.

My custom SCTProvider:

```
public class BiPROTokenProvider extends SCTProvider{

private static final String WSC_IDENTIFIER = "wsc:Identifier";
private static final String BIPRO_PRAEFIX = "bipro:";

@Override
public TokenProviderResponse createToken(TokenProviderParameters tokenParameters) {
    TokenProviderResponse response = super.createToken(tokenParameters);

    String biproId = BIPRO_PRAEFIX + response.getTokenId().split(":")[1];


    //NodeList identifier = ((Element) response.getToken()).getElementsByTagName(WSC_IDENTIFIER);
    //identifier.item(0).setTextContent(biproId);
    //Element identifier = response.getTokenId().getElementsByTagName(WSC_IDENTIFIER);

    //super.createToken(tokenParameters).setTokenId(biproId);
    response.setTokenId(biproId);

    return response;
}
```

}

My first problem is, that I do not know where I should include my custom SCT Provider? - is it possible do to it at my endpoint publish?

```
    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), securityTokenServicePortType());
   endpoint.setServiceName(securityTokenService26010().getServiceName());
      endpoint.setWsdlLocation(securityTokenService26010().getWSDLDocumentLocation().toString());  
   endpoint.publish("/SecurityTokenService-2.6.0.1.0");
   endpoint.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(soapInterceptor());
   return endpoint;
   }
    @Bean
    public DefaultInMemoryTokenStore defaulttokenStore(){
    return new DefaultInMemoryTokenStore();
    }
    @Bean 
    SCTProvider customSCTProvider(){
    return new BiPROTokenProvider();
    }
```

Second problem:
I want to store my generated token in a default tokenstore from cxf. I read something about a tokenstore. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html
In my opinion I have to include the tokenstore in the enpointproperties from service implementation.

```
    @WebService
    (
       portName = "wst:UserPasswordLogin",
       serviceName = "SecurityTokenService_2.6.0.1.0",
       wsdlLocation = "src/main/resources/wsdl/SecurityTokenService-   2.6.0.1.0.wsdl",
      endpointInterface = "net.bipro.namespace.SecurityTokenServicePortType"
       )
@EndpointProperties({

@EndpointProperty(key = "ws-security.callback-handler", value="com.muki.endpoint.STSCallbackHandler"),
//@EndpointProperty(key = "ws-security.add.inclusive.prefixes", value="false"),
@EndpointProperty(key = "org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.TokenStore", value="TOKEN_STORE_CACHE_INSTANCE"),
  })
  public class SecurityTokenEndpoint implements SecurityTokenServicePortType {
  ...
  }
```

But if I include the tokenstore via the endpoint properties, I receive the following error.

```
    <faultstring>java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.TokenStore</faultstring>
```

Can anybody help how I include a tokenstore and my custom SCT Provider?

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but I use xml configuration. Instead of `value` I used `value-ref` and passed bean there:

```
<jaxws:endpoint 
    id="endpointId" 
    address="/foo/bar" 
    ...
    serviceName="ns1:ServiceName">
    <jaxws:properties>
        ...
        <entry key="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.TokenStore" value-ref="tokenStore" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.MemoryTokenStore"/>
```

The error was gone but it wasn't working correctly - TokenStore wasn't set. So I tried another approach. Instead of editing endpoint I added that entry to bus config:

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.TokenStore" value-ref="tokenStore" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:bus>

<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.MemoryTokenStore"/>
```

As for your question, I believe your syntax would look like:

```
@EndpointProperty(key = "org.apache.cxf.ws.security.tokenstore.TokenStore", ref="bean-name")
```